# afterrender not work in tbpanel Extjs modern

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

Afterrender event not work for my tabpanel component.
code of my tabpanel:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.tabs.Tabs', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

shadow: true,
cls: 'demo-solid-background',
tabBar: {
    layout: {
        pack: 'center'
    }
},
activeTab: 1,
defaults: {
    scrollable: true
},
items: [
    {
        title: 'Tab 1',
        html : 'By default, tabs are aligned to the top of a view.',
        cls: 'card'
    },
    {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html : 'A TabPanel can use different animations by setting <code>layout.animation.</code>',
        cls: 'card'
    }
],
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(corpse) {
        console.log('afterrender');
    }
}});
```

This tab panel I use in view formpanel that added in main view like this:

```
doCompose: function (to) {
    var me = this,
        composer = me.composer,
        view = me.getView(),
        viewModel = me.getViewModel(),
        toField;

    me.hideActions();

    if (!composer) {
        me.composer = composer = view.add(
            {
            xtype: 'compose',
            flex: 1                    
        });

        if (to) {
            toField = me.lookupReference('toField');
            toField.setValue(to);
        }

        viewModel.set('composing', true);
    }
}
```

Compose it's my formpanel which contain tabpanel.
I try use example from official templates ExtJs Sencha.
View for mobile profile compose email https://github.com/syscobra/extjs-admin-dashboard-template/tree/master/modern/src

Comment: Ext-JS 6 modern TabPanel has not `afterrender` event. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.tab.Panel.html#events

Comment: @beso9595 Thank you, I not noticed, which event it is better to use then

Comment: Better to do what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i said Ext-JS 6 modern TabPanel has not afterrender event.Instead you can use [`painted`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.tab.Panel.html#event-painted), heres the 
[**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nc1)

```
listeners: {
    painted: function () {
        //your code
    }
}
```